# how to run .vbs files from java and get data and store in a variable

Tags: java

i want to run a .vbs file in java and store that output in a variable and use it in my java code . is this possible . or any other way is there .

i have tried Runtime.getruntime.exe() , but how to get output data of .vbs file to my java code

i am learning java, it would be a great help for me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

calling other programs (especially other language's) from inside a java program is advanced stuff. Getting returned data may be close to impossible unless you have your vbscript write to a file then read that back into java, or have it print to stdout and bring that into java to interpret.

This thread may be helpful to you:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/406966/java/java/capture-events-vbs-script-java